# Cannot load from byte/boolean array because "BlackWhite.marked" is null

Tags: java, graph

When I run my code below, I keep getting the error from the title of this post, although I don't know why. I tried: `Arrays.fill(marked, false);`, I am trying to figure out how many white nodes and black nodes, connect that do not exist in the `blacknodes[]`.

```
public class BlackWhite {
    private static boolean[] marked;

public BlackWhite(Graph G, int s) {
    marked = new boolean[G.V()];
    dfs(G, s);
}

public static int count(Graph G, int[] blacknodes) {
    int rw_count = 0;

    for (int w : G.adj(blacknodes.length)) {
        if (marked(w)) {
            rw_count++;
        }
    }

    return rw_count;
}

private void dfs(Graph G, int v) {
    marked[v] = true;
    for (int w : G.adj(v)) {
        if (!marked[w]) {
            dfs(G, w);
        }
    }
}

public static boolean marked(int v) {
    return marked[v];
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Graph G = new Graph(3);
    G.addEdge(1, 2);
    G.addEdge(4, 1);
    G.addEdge(1, 8);

    System.out.println(BlackWhite.count(G, new int[] { 1 })); // should print 3
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are initializing the `marked` array at the Constuctor of `BlackWhite` class. But in your main method you never called `new BlackWhite()`. So your `marked` array is still null when you are calling the static `count` method.

You should change your count method like this.

```
public static int count(Graph G, int[] blacknodes) {
    int rw_count = 0;
    if(marked == null) marked = new boolean[G.V()];

    for (int w : G.adj(blacknodes.length)) {
        if (marked(w)) {
            rw_count++;
        }
    }

    return rw_count;
}
```

Comment: Thx. How can I use DSF? How can I compare with the input array?

Comment: You can remove static from count method, and use BlackWhite blackwhite = new BlackWhite() ; and then blackWhite.count(G, new int[] { 1 })); this should invoke the constructor and run dfs on your graph.